# CSS 100% width inside div

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I couldn't word my title properly. I have got a question about my CSS code. I tried putting everything in JSfiddle but that would work, sorry.

I don't know how I can make the div 'infoMovie' extend until the end of the div 'displayMovie'.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="displayMovie">
                <div class='imageCover'>
                    <img src='Endgame-movie-cover.jpg' width="100">
                </div>
                <div class='infoMovie'>
                    <div class='imageTitle' >
                        End game
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class='imageDesc'>movie about everything in life lollllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.displayMovie {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

.imageCover {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10;
    float: left;
}

.imageDesc {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.imageTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18pt;
    margin: 5 10 5 10;
    display: inline-table;
}

.infoMovie {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So basically I want to extend infoMovie to 100% of the rest of displayMovie.

Image of how the web page looks: [image: I want to change the 'this is a movie which contains loads of action' until the end of the page]

I want to change the 'this is a movie which contains loads of action' until the end of the page

Comment: Try putting width:100% for infoMovie and overflow:hidden for displayMovie

Comment: By combining both your answer (add overflow hidden) and using an answer as seen below I fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.infoMovie {
display: inline-block;
}
```

means the `.infoMovie` `div` will be no wider than the content it contains.

You can remove this style declaration.

You want `.infoMovie` to exhibit the normal block-level behaviour of a `div` element.

As a block-level element (`<div>`), it will extend to the width of its parent, naturally.

Comment: By combining both your answer (remove display inline block) and using a previous comment on my post, overflow:hidden on .infoMovie, it was fixed. Thanks!